# RxJava: Complete stream based on condition

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have on Observable, which emits items when some data is coming from a BLE connection:

```
public interface CommunicationController {
     Flowable<DataContainer> dataReceived();
}
```

On top of this I want to build a `Observable`, which `completes` when one of the following conditions is true:

a. I receive two messages of a specific type (this is done by using `filter` operator on the received `DataContainer` item.

```
communicationController.dataReceived()
    .filter(data -> isTypeA(data) || isTypeB(data))
    .take(2)
    .toList()
    .map(dataContainers -> doSomeMappingToCommon object)
```

b. I receive one message of a specific type (again using `filter` operator).

```
communicationController.dataReceived()
    .filter(data -> isTypeC(data))
    .firstOrError()
    .map(dataContainers -> doSomeMappingToCommon object);
```

How can I combine those two `Observable`s into a single one?
Additionally only one of the two Observables will emit an item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your answer will be Observable.merge: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html

According to the documentation, this does not wait for every observable to emit something.

One option is to use merge and takeUntil: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takeuntil.html

Kotlin code:

```
val stopStream = Observable.merge(...)

streamThatWillRun = streamThatWillRun.takeUntil(stopStream)
```

Answer (score 0):

To combine 2 observables, you can use operator zipWith. Example:

```
Observable<AppMetaDataBiz> appMetaDataObservable = this.mAppRepository.getAppMetaData();

Observable<ProductBiz> productDetailsObservable =
        this.mProductRepository.getProductDetails(this.productId);

return productDetailsObservable.zipWith(appMetaDataObservable,
                                            ((jmProduct, jmAppMetaData) -> {

                                               //TODO: implement business logic

                                                return jmProduct;
                                            }));
```

Comment: Hmm, `zipWith` will not solve my problem, as it will only emit one event if both `Observable`s emit one event. In my case it's more that only one of the two observables will emit one item. I should clarify this in the question.

Comment: Hmm, I may get your idea. If I'm right, combineLatest may help you:
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html